# How to customize CK Editor's output?

Tags: html, css, ckeditor5

I just tried the minimal build of CK Editor 5.

[image]

When I checked the output code, I understood that CK Editor just wraps "Paragraph" to "p" tag, "Heading 1" to "h2" tag and "B" to "strong" tag. I am using the CSS cross-browser reset, and as BEM follower, I don't use tag selectors, so wrapping the text by tags does not change the appearace.

### Conceptual solutions

1. Create the wrapper for editable content and setup descendant selector for editable text:

```css
.CKEditorOutput p {
  /* paragraph styles */
}

.CKEditorOutput h2 {
  /* heading 2 styles */
}
```

I have feeling that there are many of pitfall here.
If so please teach me them.

2. Setup the CK editor to add certain tags to paragraphs, headings etc. If it's possible, please teach me the respective API.

Comment: I don't see any problem with solution 1, seems like the best way to go about it without affecting other elements

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, Thank you for the comment! Well, I'll do it this way.